# What does the checkbox top left in Inspector do in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

There is a checkbox in Unity (4.6) top left in Inspector. I can uncheck it to "hide" Image:s, Button:s and what not. What does it really do? Can I unhide said objects from script? I did try toggling .enabled on and off but nothing happens; if that checkbox is unchecked I have not been able to display that element again from script. It is unfortunate because when designing a 2D game field, you generally want to put all graphics onto the canvas first to fit it properly, then hide it in order to have a kind of default, empty state of the canvas design. Or else all possible labels and stuff that only are shown occasionally would clutter up the design canvas in Unity editor.

- I have not found any relevant and/or up to date documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allows you to deactivate and activate gameobjects. Non-active gameobjets will not be drawn, their `Update()` will not be called, and you will not be able to find them using `Find()` because of that, you must save reference to any object you want to turn on later in script.

Turn on/off: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

Check if explicitly turned on/off: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html

Check if turned on/off because parent was turned on/off: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html

Comment: Ok my mistake. I was accidentally trying SetActive on a saved Image reference. Of course it didn't work... doing it on the game object does. Still struggling to separate GameObjects from components and what not. Btw `Image` has a IsActive() which according to the docs is true if the related game object and the component both are true.

Answer (score 1):

that checkbox is the same as `<...thing...>.SetActive(false);` (where <...thing...> is the component or gameobject in question).

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html

once a component is set to "not active" (via script or via that checkbox) you cannot access it unless you have a stored reference to it, i.e. `GetComponent<T>()`, `Find()` and the other 'search' functions cannot see it.

if you had a "controller" script with var's for the various text/images/whatever you wanted to activate via script and drag/dropped the objects in the inspector you would have your references. Alternatively you can use a script to get the references in a `start()` function and then set them to active=false.

this unity answer covers off the enabled vs active quite nicely: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/25945/what-is-the-difference-between-these-three-ways-of.html